# conditional re-download of website data based on timestamp

Tags: ruby, mechanize

In simple form I re-download a file from my account on a website if my local copy of **data.csv** is older than 1 hour:

```
# Mission: make sure data*.csv is most current whenever called
def updateData  
  return if File.exists?("data.csv") && (Time.now - File::Stat.new("data.csv").mtime) < 3600

  $agent = Mechanize.new
  $agent.pluggable_parser.default = Mechanize::Download  

  $page = $agent.get("http://website.com/login.jsp")
# login etc.
  $agent.get("/getdata!downLoad.action").save("data.csv")
end
```

However they mentioned that updates to my data are only published thrice daily: at 16:45, 18:45, and 22:45.

Question:
How do I make my code more intelligent about grabbing the update only if my copy is older than the last update time (including yesterday's)?

Some array `["16:45", "18:45", "22:45"]` could help but I'm not sure what next in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could do it :

```
require 'time'

current = Time.now.strftime("%H%M")
past = File::Stat.new("data.csv").mtime.strftime("%H%M")
if (current > '2245' and past < '2245') or (current > '1845' and past < '1845') or (current > '1645' and past < '1645') or (File::Stat.new("data.csv").mtime.day != Time.now.day and current > '1645')
    #update
end
```

You will also need to change the way you store `mtime`. It will need to be in the form `hhmm`. You would set `mtime` like this `mtime = Time.now.hour.to_s + Time.now.min.to_s` when you create the csv.

Comment: `File::Stat.new("filename").mtime.class => Time` mtime is a value of type Time built-in to the File core gem; I don't store nor define it. I see what you are doing with the `if...and..or...etc` but was hoping for a general solution (any number of daytimes that are each variable)

Comment: That should work now. The reason I don't compare the full time (yy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss) because I think it's easier to only work with `hh:mm`, `hhmm` are the only two things that decide whether you need to update or not.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `past = t.strftime("%H:%M")?`  Otherwise both 02:24 and 22:04 get turned into "224".

Comment: @WayneConrad I confirmed that issue, i.e. 17:04 gets "174"  . Anyway maybe the series of OR's can be turned in some `eval`ed for loop to deal with an arbitrary number of daytimes, not only 3

Comment: The script needs to take the day into account: If it runs at 2250 today and the file was modified at 2240 yesterday, it won't update (but should).

Comment: if current(2250) > 2245 and past(2240) < 2245 : Those times satisfy the first part of that logic. Although you are correct if we say that past(2250) and current(1650). I've update the answer to include that.

Comment: Somehow the typical boolean-logic precedence of AND over OR didn't kick in here.  After some troubleshooting I had to code with parens: `(current > '2245' and past < '2245') or (current > '1845' and past < '1845') or (current > '1645' and past < '1645')`

Comment: I looked it up. `and` / `or` have the same precedence. Either use `()` or use `&&` which has higher precedence than the `or`